# Can't load Catalyst Control Center. Shrunken screen

Tags: windows-10, graphics-card, amd-radeon

I have a ATI Radeon 4800 graphics card. My monitor display was shrinking so I tried opening Catalyst Control Center to change the scaling setting. When I tried opening the Control Center It gives this error: Catalyst Control Center cannot be started, there are currently no settings that can be configured using the control centre.

Summary:

1. Can't get into Catalyst Control Center
2. Uninstalled ATI driver an restarted
3. Installed ATI 4800 driver
4. Still can't open Catalyst Control Center

Also the fan is running unusually loud at all times

Comment: ATI (now part of AMD) introduced the Radeon 4800 in 2008. You can try to clean the card from dust but it might be time to replace it.

Comment: @spike_66 how can I tell if the card is gone bad?

Comment: You wrote that the display was shrinking. This usually means that the computer graphics can no longer handle a higher resolution.

Comment: Please look at the [updated question](https://superuser.com/questions/1271750/installed-new-video-card-computer-stuck-in-scanning-and-reparing-drive-screen)