# Installed new video card; Computer stuck in Scanning and repairing drive screen

Tags: windows-10, gpu, amd-radeon

My PC's display (ATI Radeon HD 4870 GPU) had shrunk, so I uninstalled the driver and restarted. When my PC booted the driver was somehow still there. I removed the GPU and installed a new one (MSI Radeon HD 4650). My PC is stuck in this screen:

> Scanning and Repairing drive (C:) 0%

I switched the GPU back to the old one and my computer started up as normal

Is this because I did not uninstall the previous driver? If so how can I fix this?

Comment: No, these two things should be unrelated. You should run a `chkdsk /f` from an elevated command prompt and reboot when prompted to perform a disk check. That is the same thing your OS was trying to do, and usually indicates the computer was not shut down improperly the previous time.

Comment: I updated windows and restarted the PC. Now it works fine. I don't know how it got fixed